# Only first element in a react.createElement is rendered

Tags: reactjs, svg, createelement

I need to render dynamicaly an `img`. Here is my function that translate my logos to components :

```
import {ReactComponent as MyLogo1} from '../assets/img/logo1.svg'
import {ReactComponent as MyLogo2} from '../assets/img/logo2.svg'
import {ReactComponent as MyLogo3} from '../assets/img/logo3.svg'

export const logoToComponent: any = {
    logo_1: MyLogo1,
    logo_2: MyLogo2,
    logo_3: MyLogo3
};
```

and then I render it like this :

```
[...]

const logo: any = (key: string, props: any) => {
        return logoToComponent[key] ? React.createElement(logoToComponent[key], props) : null;
    };

return (
[...]
{logo(`logo_${category.code}`, { className: "mx-auto mb-3 w-6 h-6" })}
[...]
)
```

The problem is, only the first logo is rendered. In my DOM, when I inspect, every logos are there but only the first one is visible. And in my SVGs, the fill is set for each logos.

Any idea why React only render the first element ?

***PS:*** If I **delete** the first line in my logoToComponent function, the second is visible and not the following ones.

Comment: If they're in the DOM, then React *is* rendering them all. It sounds like there's a styling issue causing only one to be visible, but not a React issue

Comment: But by inspecting, I am 100% that the first element has exactly the same classes than the second and third one. I don't see a reason there

Comment: It sounds like maybe they're being displayed on top of one another? It's really impossible to say, and I'm not a CSS expert. All I know is that it doesn't sound like an issue with the React part of your code

Comment: I just added an info in my post. If I delete the first element, the second will be visible (in good position) and not the following ones. If I delete the 2 first, the third one will be visible (at the right place) and not the following etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer in case it can help.

Every SVG had the same id "clip-path". I just set a unique id in each SVG, and it works fine.